# How to convert DateTimepicker value to date datatype?

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, datetimepicker

My database is:

```
create table bus
( bus_no varchar(10),
  jdate date,
  source varchar(20),
  destination varchar(20),
  departtime varchar(10),
  primary key(bus_no,jdate));
```

C#

```
c.connect();
comm = new OracleCommand(); /*Class OracleCommand  represents an SQL statement or stored procedure to execute against a database. OracleCommand() initializes a new instance of the OracleCommand. */
comm.Connection = c.conn;
//Console.Write(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO bus VALUES ('" + busno.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "','" + source.Text + "','" + destination.Text + "','" + departtime.Text + "')";
comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
MessageBox.Show("Bus Added");
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
c.conn.Close();
```

It's showing error as month is not recognized. Please help.

Comment: Could you please post the exact error message in the Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use custom formatter to format it to correct format. Generally default short string of C# not work with Oracle.

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

or

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("M/d/yyyy")
```

Comment: I am happy that i can able to help you

Comment: This will work only if your current session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` settings is also `MM/DD/YYYY`. Since it can be changed at any time by the user you should not rely on this!

Comment: i don't understand how can user change the NLS_DATE_FORMAT. It can be done only by DB Admin. I am agree with you if  NLS_DATE_FORMAT change to some weird format, then Saketan need to change the format. In my experience "MM/dd/yyyy" format working for me, since last 5 years as we not keep changing NLS_DATE_FORMAT of oracle every now and then

Answer (score 0):

You should never use concatenated SQL strings in your applications. Parameterized queries will be faster and help you to avoid `SQL Injection` and troubles with type conversion.

```
c.connect();
comm = new OracleCommand(); /*Class OracleCommand  represents an SQL statement or stored procedure to execute against a database. OracleCommand() initializes a new instance of the OracleCommand. */
comm.Connection = c.conn;
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO bus VALUES (:bus_no, :jdate, :source, :destination, :departtime)";
comm.Parameters.Add("bus_no",  busno.Text);
comm.Parameters.Add("jdate", dateTimePicker1.Value);
comm.Parameters.Add("source", source.Text);
comm.Parameters.Add("destination", destination.Text);
comm.Parameters.Add("departtime", departtime.Text);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Bus Added");
c.conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for tip. I am not aware of such things as I am beginner.